# Adding 'class' as dict key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am able to do this:

```
{'class': 'foo'}
```

But when I do this:

```
dict(class='foo')
```

I get:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
     {'class':}
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why can't python use 'class' as a **kwarg? It can just as easily use list, int, len... as keyword arguments.

Comment: Your error message does not match the code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`list`, `int`, and `len` are not keywords, they are normal identifiers. `class` is a [keyword](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).